# Read NSArray of CGPoints in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsarray

I have a function in an Objective-C class that returns an NSArray:

```
- (NSArray *) myAwesomeFunction {
   // Good stuff here
   return array
}
```

Now I know that the members of this array are all `NSValue` objects with a `CGPoint` inside. This information is not available to Swift however, which infers the return type (correctly) as `[AnyObject]!`

Now when I try to cast the members of the array into an `NSValue` I get a cast error as I should.

```
let myArray = AnObjectiveCClass.myAwesomeFunction()
let myValue = myArray[0] as NSValue // Cast error since AnyObject cannot be cast to NSValue
```

This leaves me with a problem though, how can I access the contents of the array in my Swift class? In the end I want to retrieve the CGPoint values inside of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you can cast the the whole array to a `[NSValue]` array:

```
if let downcastNSValueArray = myArray as? [NSValue] {
    let myValue = downcastNSValueArray[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an Objective-C [generics annotation](http://www.miqu.me/blog/2015/06/09/adopting-objectivec-generics/) to your method:

```
+ (NSArray<NSValue *> *) myAwesomeMethod {
   // Good stuff here
   return array;
}
```

Now Swift automatically infers the type:

```
let myArray = MyClass.myAwesomeMethod()
let myValue = myArray[0]
let myPoint = myValue.pointValue
```

Note that `myArray` will be an implicitly-unwrapped optional i.e. an `[NSValue]!`, so you could also add [nullability annotations](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) if you know `myAwesomeMethod` won't ever return `nil`. `myValue` will be considered non-optional. So the code above doesn't need any additional type handling to satisfy the compiler, but may still trigger runtime exceptions if `myArray == nil` or if `myArray.count < 1`.